# Python 3.5 - tkinter Label sticky error: which submodule to load to prevent use of "import *"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am building an app that uses tkinter as a GUI. It currently works fine so I am optimizing my code. I've read online that the use of `from module import *` must best be avoided. Right now, my working code uses `from tkinter import *`.

My code has the following label:

```
Label(image=IMG).grid(row=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)
```

However, when I change `from tkinter import *` into `from tkinter import Label` I am getting the error:

> NameError: name 'W' is not defined

So my question is, how can I find which submodule (if that is the correct name for it?) of tkinter is responsible for the definition of the sticky values?

**NB**: I have found that using `import tkinter` and applying `sticky=tkinter.W` does indeed work, but I am guessing this has the same risks as using `from tkinter import *`? So I would still like to find the correctly specified imports.

Comment: no, `import tkinter` does not have the same risks as `from tkinter import *`. `import tkinter` is exactly how you do it, though I favor `import tkinter as tk` to help with readability later in the code.

Comment: Thnx Bryan for the extra insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because you have not imported Tkinter constants like the `W` you use in `sticky=W`. You can either do `from tkinter.constants import W` (`from tkinter import W` also works) or just replace its value and do `sticky='w'`.

Indeed, all Tkinter constants are just strings, so they can all be replaced by a string (`DISABLED` by `'disabled'` ...)

Comment: Thnx that worked! I had indeed already tried `from tkinter import constants`, but that didn't do the trick. Did not know I had to import W from tkinter.constants instead. However, reading your full answer, I decided to go for `sticky='w'` in the end. Works great, thnx.